# Iphone dev sqlite query error for retrieving specific records

Tags: iphone

i have a requirement of retrieving specific amount of records from sqlite database at a time, now in this query i am trying to retrieve 0 to 20 records from database, but its not working, plz. tell me what i am doing wrong, here is my query

```
NSString *sqlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM Apns ORDER BY NotificationMessage LIMIT '%d', '%d'",a,b];    

const char *sql = [sqlStr UTF8String];
```

here a is an integer containg 0 and b also an integer containing 20 in it (a and b can contain different values other than 0 and 20 according to user wish or requirement). i want to fetch these record and dispaly them in a table view but that query is not working please guide me in this, thanx and Regards. Saad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the `'` is wrong.

```
NSString *sqlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM Apns ORDER BY NotificationMessage LIMIT %d,%d",a,b];
```

Comment: Thanx Vignesh but if user wants to get the records from 10 to 30 or may be from 20 to 35 then what will i do?.

Comment: Limit is to limit the number of records retrieved.

Comment: It is correct to use "LIMIT 10, 30", try to debug you db - run this query in sqlite database browser to see result

Comment: I can't understand, please explain a little, and if Limit cant fulfill my requirement, then can you tell me that how to go about for my requirement., user will tell us the index of first and last records he/she need. so how should we cater this.

Comment: @SaadUmar. You can use ROWID to get it. Select * from table Where ROWID > min And ROWID < Max. I am not sure your order by will work in that case.

Comment: i run this in sqlite data base browser and got no error, now i dont know why its not working in the code.  SELECT * FROM Apns ORDER BY NotificationMessage LIMIT 0,20

Comment: @SaadUmar I am sorry. It works well. I added a ' which got me wrong.

Comment: That means there is nothing wrong with my query, the problem is lying somewhere else in the code, ok i will check my code again.anyways thanx again.

Comment: and u suggested ' is wrong, how? its part of the syntax isn't it?

Comment: It should be integer type, but when you add ' will interpreted as string.Check the query in the answer.